# Does orange transfrom categorial variables into dummy variables when using hierarchical clustering?

Tags: clustering, orange

I am using Orange to cluster a large amount of data consisting of three attributes. Each attribute only contains categorical unordered variables. My question is does Orange transform categorical variables into dummy variables when using Distances and Hierarchical clustering widgets on such a data set?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation states](https://docs.biolab.si//3/data-mining-library/reference/distance.html#handling-discrete-and-missing-data) this is *not* the case. Categorical values are compared as either same or different.